# How can I serve very large files (with resumable downloads) from Node / Express?

Tags: node.js, express, large-files

I'd like to allow users to download files in the range of 1GB - 1TB, so my ideal solution:

1. streams, to avoid memory issues
2. supports pausing & resuming downloads

How can I do this in my Node / Express app?

Comment: you would need some type of desktop client which could handle the download marker location so downloads could be resumed etc